# Releasing CGImage (CGImageRef)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm curious if I'm following proper memory management with CGImageRef, which I'm passing through several methods (since it's CG object, I assume it doesn't support autorelease). Memory management with non-NSObjects and interaction with other NSObjects is still somewhat new to me.

Here what I'm doing:

I'm creating the CGImageRef inside my image cache manager with CGBitmapContextCreateImage (retain count 1), and adding it to the NSMutableDictionary (retain count 2).

When CALayers use the image, I assign with layer.contents (retain count +1), and clearing contents with layer.contents = nil (retain count -1) before removing the layer.

Finally, when clearing the texture, I call CGImageRefRelease and [NSMutableDictionary removeObject] to have retain count as 0.

Is this a proper way to do so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Core Foundation objects (which all Core Graphics objects are) do support autorelease.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html)

The steps you describe should work just fine and not leak or over-release the object.

I use `CFRelease` instead of specific-class release functions like `CGImageRelease`, but purely as a matter of style. I just have to beware of `NULL`: `CGImageRelease` checks for `NULL`, whereas `CFRelease` will crash when passed `NULL`. Using `CGImageRelease` and its siblings means you don't have to worry about this.

I'm assuming you meant `removeObject:forKey:`, not `removeObject` (which doesn't exist and wouldn't have somewhere to specify an object anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the link, great resource, clarifies a lot.

Docs mentioned that CGImageRelease won't cause an error if image is NULL, so sounded safer to go with.

removeObject:forKey:, yes, that one.

Comment: **The document you link to doesn't support your claim.** Some Core Foundation objects are "toll-free bridged" to Cocoa classes, but not all are. You can cast a `CFStringRef` to a `NSString *` and vice versa, but you cannot do so with `CGImageRef` and `UIImage`.

Comment: My claim is that CF objects support `release` and `autorelease`. That document explicitly says so: “Note from the example that the memory management functions and methods are also interchangeable—you can use `CFRelease` with a Cocoa object and `release` and `autorelease` with a Core Foundation object.” Furthermore, the CGImage reference says that CGImage descends from CFType: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/

Comment: So, in a nutshell, **yes it does.**

Comment: I thought it was referring to toll-free bridged objects, which are a subset of CFTypes, based on: "Table 1 provides a list of the data types that are interchangeable between Core Foundation and Foundation." Also, at the bottom of the page: "**Note:** Not all data types are toll-free bridged, even though their names might suggest that they are. For example, NSRunLoop is not toll-free bridged to CFRunLoop, NSBundle is not toll-free bridged to CFBundle, and NSDateFormatter is not toll-free bridged to CFDateFormatter." Are you saying you can cast *any* CFType to NSObject and autorelease it?

Comment: Yes. The Carbon-Cocoa Integration Guide explicitly says that “you can use … `release` and `autorelease` with a Core Foundation object”, and anything whose class descends from CFType is a Core Foundation object (as evidenced by the fact that you can use CF functions like `CFRetain`, `CFCopyDescription`, etc. on it).

Comment: This isn't the same as toll-free bridging, though. You can't say `[myCGImage performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(…) withObject:…]`, because a CGImage is not an NSObject.

Comment: `CFRelease()` ≠ `CGImageRelease()`. I'm pretty sure `CFRelease()` will crash if you pass `NULL`, however it's safe to pass `NULL` to `CGImageRelease()`

Comment: @nielsbot: Good catch! I didn't know that at the time. I still use CFRelease (with `NULL` checks as appropriate) for style reasons, so I'll have to think about how to edit that into my answer.